# transfer data from aws python lambda to javascript

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda

I have a lambda that returns a list of strings.

```
referenceWords = ['red','orange','blue','black','white','green']
return json.dumps(referenceWords)
```

On JS side:

```
console.log(result);
console.log(typeof result);

var r = JSON.parse(result);
console.log(typeof r);

for(s in r)
{
    console.log(typeof(s) + " :" + s + ":");
    addCheckbox(s);
}
```

This seems to return:

```
["red","orange","blue","black","white","green"]
object
string :0:
string :1:
string :2:
string :3:
string :4:
string :5:
```

Can somebody help me understand why the for loop is printing integers and not the string values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Javascript when you use `for` loop. It's will return `key` value which is array key and `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`

You could get the `value` by using `r[s]`